# what is size of Empty file ? i'm getting 220 byte (4KB) size of empty file. why?

Tags: types, operating-system, int, filesystems, size

i'm getting 220 byte (4KB) size of empty file. why ?

[information for empty file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PElAY.png)

Comment: can you attach the file (using dropbox, gdrive, etc) ?

Comment: https://i.stack.imgur.com/PElAY.png

Comment: your file is RTF file, even it is empty, it still contains metada. To check it, please open your Untitle.rtf with other Text Editor (like Atom, VScode, Sublime, etc)

Comment: What makes you think that the file is empty?